# Post-meta data author and date for specific category

Tags: wordpress, posts

I want display post-meta like author and date for specific categories only, like i have 3 types of categories blogs,news, comments , now remove post-meta like author and post date from blogs and news category posts.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use wordpress neat function is_category() and where the parameters you need to give are your blogs,news, comments

Now for eg if you want to display in single page where posts from these categories only need to show up then you must have these three categories id and you can apply conditions like

```
if(is_category('1','2','3')){
//your codes here
}
```

Take reference from this

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/

Answer (score 0):

Create a new custom category template.

```
1. Inside you theme folder duplicate the category.php file.
2. Rename the duplicated copy to something like category-news or category-23(whatever you prefer which must match with the category slug or ID respectively).
3. then change the content of that file.
```

Whenever you navigate to that category(slug=news or id=23), wordpress automatically looks for category template(slug or Id) that matches the target category page something like (category-news.php or category-23.php files) if the file isn't found it moves to category.php.